# Detecting the character entered into an input field on keydown

Tags: javascript

**The Question:** How can I detect the character that is going to be inserted into an input field after keypress / keydown?

**The Background:** I'm creating an input field that is dynamically expanding and shrinking as the user types.  In order to do this fluidly I need to redraw immediately before the character is rendered. In order to redraw to the correct width, I need to know the character that is about to be inserted.  Using keyup and then .val() creates a jittery interface because the width isn't changed until after the text shifts to the right.

**Explored Approaches:**

This is what I'm using now, but it doesn't do the trick simply because it is not an accurate mapping, especially for special characters.

```
        // Convert the keypress to the appropriate letter
        self.lastLetter = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        self.lastLetter = e.shiftKey?self.lastLetter:self.lastLetter.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a module called [keysight](https://github.com/fresheneesz/keysight) that translates `keypress`, `keydown`, and `keyup` events into characters and keys respectively.

Keysight retruns an object that has a `char` property, and a `key` property. The `char` property represents the character being typed, which takes into account uppercase. The `key` property represents the key on the keyboard and doesn't represent upper or lower case - just the key.

Example:

```
 element.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
    var character = keysight(event).char
    if(character === 'w') {
      console.log("got lower case w")
    } else if(character === 'W') {
      console.log("got upper case W")

      var key = keysight(event).key
      console.log("keysight(event).key is still lower case "+key)
    }
 })
```

Comment: Very cool!  Does your library keep track of whether shift was being held (if the character is uppercase / lowercase?)

Comment: Yes indeed. I'll update my answer with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure from the small snippet you've posted, but it looks like you're trying to map character codes to characters. The `keypress` event does indeed pass character codes. The `keydown` (and `keyup`) events, however, pass scan codes instead of character codes. That's so they can pass key strokes that don't represent characters (such as arrow keys, hot keys, etc.). You can find a table of scan codes in this [blog post](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm), but note that they're browser and OS specific.